# error: Setup script exited with error: SandboxViolation

Tags: python, setup.py

**when i'm try to install python setup.py in a windows command prompt it gives the error like this:**

command:python setup.py install

error: Setup script exited with error: SandboxViolation: mkdir('C:\Users\abc~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-x6pech6b\python-axolotl-curve25519-0.4.1.post2\build', 511) {}

The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.

please help to solve this error,

thanks..

Answer (score -4):

I'll quote the question:

> Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.

That's the answer.

Open an(other) issue at https://github.com/tgalal/python-axolotl-curve25519/issues/new.